# How to open a file with an executable already open?

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a C#/WPF project that represents a dbf editor that allows you to open files in 3 ways:
- with apposit button in toolbar
- with drag & drop
- with double click on file
Now i use a TabControl that contain every dbf open.
I can handle it with my internal button and drag add item to container.
if I open a file with the double click and there is an open instance I would like to add it to the container and instead open a new instance.
My code :

- App

public partial class App : Application
{

```
private static Editor mainWindow = null;
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Editor mainWindow = new Editor(e.Args);
    mainWindow.Show();
}
```

}

- Editor:

  public partial class Editor : Window
          {

  ```
              ChooseMessage.Choose choose;
              public Dictionary<int, DBFStructure> ds;
              string DbfName;
              private string[] OldNew;
              public Editor(string[] e)
              {
                  InitializeComponent();
                  ds = new Dictionary<int, DBFStructure>();
                  OldNew = new string[2];
                  choose = ChooseMessage.Choose.OK;
                  if (e.Length > 0)
                      if (File.Exists(e[0]) && e[0].EndsWith(".dbf", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                          EffOpen(e[0]);
               }
             private void dbf_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
              {
                  if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) == true)
                  {
                      string filename = ((string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true))[0];
                      if (File.Exists(filename) && filename.EndsWith(".dbf", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                          EffOpen(filename);
                  }
              }
      ....
      }
  ```

I apologize for code display but I can not set it correctly.

my problem is to intercept the opening of a dbf from the last open editor instance and add it to the controltab, otherwise create a new instance.

P.S. EffOpen(filename) represents the method that, by passing the fil name, loads it and adds it to the container

Thanks to all

Comment: There is no mechanism in Windows to detect that another process opens a file.  It is not entirely impossible, after all an anti-malware product does this.  But requires the kind of OS patching that you can't do with C#.  And shouldn't do in any language, bugs are very destabilizing to the user's machine.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file with a double click, a new application instance will be started by Windows. This is by design, you cannot change this.

In this new instance you have no direct references to the objects of your first application instance, so you cannot just add the file being opened to the `TabControl` of the first instance.

You need to implement it like that:

- since you can open files via double click, your application can handle files using the command line arguments - that's good
- you need a way to check whether there is an instance already running - use a `Mutex` with a dedicated and unique name to do that; try creating a `Mutex` on app startup and check the `out` parameter of the `Mutex(bool, string, out bool)` constructor - if it's `false`, then there is an instance already
- you need a way to tell the already running instance that it needs to open a file that has been passed as the command line argument to the second instance; use any of the [inter-proc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) methods that better suits you: a `NamedPipe` would be a pretty simple way